# Including and referring to jQuery as a file in an iNotes-form in Domino Designer

Tags: javascript, jquery, lotus-domino

We are trying to use jQuery in Domino Designer. When I create a library, post the code of jQuery in the editor and try to save, Domino designer complains about compile errors, which turns out to be a reported [bug](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21247172)!

Our clients are using old versions of Domino and we can't expect such a bug to be fixed on their machiens.
Anyway, there seems to be some [solutions](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-t-import-jquery-into-lotus-notes-library).

In my case, I have to go for adding jQuery as a file. The problem is that the old application we are modifying is forms-based. In XPages, one could refer to the lib like this:

```
<xp:script src="/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
```

Where the js-library would reside in the resources/files folder in the iNotes application.

However, in a form, I can only refer to libraries included explicitly in the libraries folder.
Is there a way to include the js-file, whose path is reachable, in a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery in forms is as almost easy as in XPages: Just go to the HTML- header- section of the form and do exactly the same, but with a "script"- Tag:

Here is the formula I used for jquery, jquery,cookie and jquery-ui:

```
"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/" + @WebDbName + 
    "/jquery.js\"></script>" +
"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/" + @WebDbName + 
    "/jquery.cookie.js\"></script>" +
"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/" + @WebDbName + 
    "/jquery-ui.js\"></script>"
```

Usually It should work without the @WebDbName as well, but I found out, that there might be conditions (e.g. Form embedded in a frameset in another app) where this is not safe.

Comment: I am glad to hear that someone is using JQuery in Domino! Your solution worked, the library is being loaded. The problem is still that it is not compiling! I downloaded jquery2.1.1 and I am receiving a compilation error from the web browser!

Comment: I've just found out that the older version, 1.1.1, works fine!